# Ubuntu 9.10 + MonoDevelop + Debug + NUnit

Tags: linux, debugging, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I am a Linux noob and I would like to debug a unit test.

If I run my test in MonoDevelop it goes green but if I try to debug everything freeze and I have to stop the debugger. My breakpoint on first line of code is never hit. There is no stack trace or information of what could have failed.

Edit 1: Should I install OpenSuse (since it is Novell and they are behind Mono) instead of Ubuntu ?

Comment: It's going to be really hard to answer your question without more information.  Can you give us any code?  I don't think it should matter what distribution you're using.

Comment: My code is the simplest possible : string test = "test";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger in MonoDevelop is a bit flaky, but any number of things could be causing problems, the MonoDevelop team hangs out at #MonoDevelop on irc.gnome.org. They are quite friendly and can probably help you diagnose your issue.

I've been using Mono/MonoDevelop on Ubuntu for 2-3 years now and have had no reason to move away from Ubuntu. Although I use the [Monoxide PPA](https://launchpad.net/~directhex/+archive/monoxide) as a source for MonoDevelop, rather than the version from the standard distribution. The Monoxide PPA is more in sync with the most recent changes to MonoDevelop, and there is a pretty high churn rate on the codebase of MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity you should go with the openSUSE vmware client.  I selected openSUSE as I wanted to just focus on Mono and not take on the additional challenge of installing and configuring the entire environment.  I have had any issues thus far.